# Is space-time curvature same for all observers?

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, curvature, observers

Since tensors are invariant under coordinate transformations, and a moving observer is just in another coordinate system, he should measure the same Riemann curvature tensor (with different components).

Is that right for all observers, regardless of how they move, whether or not they are in an inertial reference frame?

Comment: Tensors are not invariant under coordinate transformations in general, only scalars (Rank zero tensors) are invariant under coordinate transformations.

Comment: To avoid a situation where your question is completely answered by a simple "yes" or "no," perhaps you could add some context as to why you feel that you don't already know the answer.

Comment: @SidhaarthKumar looks like you don’t understand at all what tensors are. Invariance is a basic tensor property.

Comment: @J.Murray I already know the answer, was just crosschecking.

Comment: @Nayeem1 Whether you know the answer or not is immaterial - at the present moment, the answer to your question is one word long, which makes your question a [bad fit for the site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6669/156895). It would be easy to change this by adding context (*I think the answer is yes, but [...] is raising some doubt in my mind*), which would allow for an answer which would be helpful to others and quite possibly extend your current understanding as well.

Comment: I edited the question and added more.

Comment: @Sidhaarth Kumar. The components of tensors transform according to the prescribed rules, however, the form of the tensor equations remain the same in all coordinate systems.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus I agree that the equations of general relativity should be covariant in nature (that is, that their form is coordinate independent) but what does one mean then for a tensor to be invariant? The only meaningful attribution to invariance I can think of is that of invariance of the components under a coordinate transformation (which means its a rank zero tensor). Would be good to know if you agree with what I'm saying here or if there is some glaring oversight in my understanding.

Comment: @SidhaarthKumar all tensors are invariant under coordinate transformations - regardless of their ranks. Basis may change, components accordingly - to keep the tensor invariant.

Comment: I agree, think I thought you meant invariant in the sense of the components. My bad!

Comment: @SidhaarthKumar invariance of tensors mean only one thing in tensor algebra. There is no such thing called 'invariant in the sense of components'.

Comment: To say that a tensor is not invariant because its components are basis-dependent is like saying that my friend William becomes a different person when I choose to call him Bill.

Comment: @Sidhaarth Kumar. I agree with you; I think you got it. It is just that your language was imprecise; mine is often so as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a matter of semantics. Is the velocity vector of a moving particle the same in all coordinates? Yes, under rotations, no under boosts--if you don't consider components, but the geometric object that the velocity vector represents.

What about a Schwarzschild blackhole? We all know the metric...but you will see science news talk about rouge blackholes roaming the galaxy? They are moving, so the Schwarzschild metric doesn't work. But the metric in the moving coordinates represents the same geometric object, with the same spacetime curvature (well, the Einstein tensor is zero everywhere but the singularity...but even the Riemann tensor..it's components are different but it represents the same thing).

One thing that is popular now is coordinate-independent statements of physical law, e.g.:

$$ \vec F = q(\vec E + \vec v \times \vec B) $$

It's true, independent of coordinates, but certainly the force, velocity, electric and magnetic fields depend on the coordinate system.

So are they different, or are they the same? idk. Semantics.

Also: you specify inertial coordinate systems in the question. General relativity removes this constraint.

If you are near a Kerr blackhole, and chose a coordinate system that feels no centrifugal force...you *are* rotating with respect to distant star (or whatever you choose to define stationary), but it's still a Kerr metric. Inside the ergosphere, you are even moving w.r.t to aforementioned "stationary". Still Kerr blackhole metric.

I think that GR being "invariant under coordinate diffeomorphisms" really removes all this concerns, we just have a habit of thinking non-relativistically in the simplest coordinate available.

tl;dr: idk.

Comment: "rouge blackholes" :-) Apparently even though they have no hair black holes still wear make up :-)

Comment: At the end of the day there are *useful* distinctions between basis free and coordinate dependent thought.

Comment: @JohnRennie ikr, they are absolutely radiant.

Answer (score 1):

A tensor is a geometric object and so has properties (such as the coefficients of its characteristic polynomial) that are independent of the basis in which we choose to represent the tensor, *provided* that the basis consists of orthonormal vectors. So the invariant properties of a tensor are invariant under rotations and reflections of our basis.

Two reference frames that are moving relative to one another at a constant velocity are related by a Lorentz transformation which can be though of as a rotation in four-space. Therefore the invariant properties of a physical tensor such as the Riemannian curvature tensor will be same in either reference frame. So all inertial observers will measure the same local curvature of spacetime at a given point in spacetime.

Note however that this does *not* apply to non-inertial reference frames.  An inertial and a non-inertial observer will measure different local curvatures at the same point in space time.

Comment: I hope people will vote this post up because it answers the question in a more direct fashion; not that JEB's answer is in any way wrong.

Comment: "An inertial and a non-inertial observer will measure different local curvatures at the same point in space time." --  Are you saying an inertial and non-inertial observer will construct *different* Riemann curvature tensors over a neighborhood of events?

Comment: @Aiden Not just curvature tensors with different components, but tensors with different invariants *if* they each use a local reference frame in which they are stationary. Of course, the non-inertial observer could realise that they are non-inertial (by observing pseudo-forces, for example) and correct for this, in effect creating an inertial reference frame.